# query returning blank row blank after adapter.update

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to update my sql data base using data adapter in a while loop. First loop is good but when I update the database and then in the second loop the row is blank for the select query.  Does the adapter lock the database?

```
 while (true)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand selectCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    selectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Status";
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand))
                    {
                        using (MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
                        {
                            using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
                            {
                                adapter.Fill(table);
                                table.Rows[0][1] = "data-" + count.ToString();
                                adapter.Update(table);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: post some code, what have you tried, its helps us to help you